# Find a compact formula

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find a compact formula of the following sum:

$$\sum_{j=0} ^ n \binom{n}{j} (-1)^j (n-j)^{n+k}  $$

for $n, k \in N $

I have tried to prove it combinatorially, but I have no idea how to interpret factor $(-1)^j$.

Edit: Using inclusion-exlusion rule I can prove $$ \sum_{j=0} ^ n \binom{n}{j} (-1)^j (n-j)^{n}$$ is a number of all surjective functions. But I don't how to cope with $k$?

Comment: HINT: inclusion exclusion principle, interpret this sum.

Comment: exactly! Don't bother by $k$ it's just a constant. Functions are from set of $n+k$ elements to set of $n$ elements.

Comment: Look at surjections from $[n+k]$ to $[n]$: for a given $j$-element subset $S$ of $[n]$, $(n-j)^{n+k}$ is the number of functions from $[n+k]$ to $[n]$ whose ranges are disjoint from $S$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Thank you for help, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to prove it but your sum is $n!*S(n+k,n)$, where $S$ is the Stirling number of the second kind: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html (Your formula is on that page.)

Basically your sum represents the number of ways you can partition $n+k$ elements into $n$ nonempty sets, where the order of the subsets matters.